# Quickly change audio device in KDE

Tags: audio, kde, opensuse, kde-4, opensuse-13.2

I recently switched to OpenSUSE (with KDE) from Windows, and I'm still going through the learning curve.

I switch fairly frequently between using my headphones with built-in microphone, and using my monitor's built-in speakers and my webcam's microphone. Using the Phonon menu through KMix (example below), I'm able to re-arrange the devices to put the one I want to use on top, but I'd prefer to be able to do it with a hotkey, similar to what the [Audio Switcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audioswitcher/) application does on Windows. When I do it, I'd also like to set the Master channel to the new one as well so I can easily adjust the audio.

[image]

Is there a way through some script that would allow me to (a) select a new default audio playback and audio recording device on the fly, (b) while also setting the master channel to that same playback device (c) with a hotkey or other quick method on the desktop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most GUI kits use same backend PulseAudio. Use `pactl` to write control script.

```
NAME
       pactl - Control a running PulseAudio sound server

DESCRIPTION
       pactl can be used to issue control commands to the PulseAudio sound server.

       pactl only exposes a subset of the available operations. For the full set use the pacmd(1).
```

**Source:** `man pactl`

1. To check available output sinks

   ```
   $ pactl list short sinks
   0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   ```
2. To check available input sources

   ```
   $ pactl list short sources
   0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   ```
3. To check default

   ```
   $ pactl info
   Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
   Library Protocol Version: 30
   Server Protocol Version: 30
   Is Local: yes
   Client Index: 2
   Tile Size: 65472
   User Name: user
   Host Name: userpc
   Server Name: pulseaudio
   Server Version: 6.0
   Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
   Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
   Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
   Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
   ```
4. To set default

   ```
   pactl set-default-source id-or-name
   pactl set-default-sink id-or-name
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   pactl set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
   pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
   ```

   or:

   ```
   pactl set-default-source 2
   pactl set-default-sink 1
   ```

**Notes:**

- This will affect only new streams, you have to move the current running streams, so use:

  ```
  pacmd move-sink-input <stream-id> <sink-id/name>
  ```

  Nice example to copy from: [Switching to HDMI Audio when HDMI is plugged into a laptop (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458194/switching-to-hdmi-audio-when-hdmi-is-plugged-into-a-laptop-14-04/)
- Some cards has multiple switchable ports, May be the one you want is not the default.

  Check for available ports:

  ```
  $pactl list sinks
  Sink #1
      State: RUNNING
      Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
      Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
      Driver: module-alsa-card.c
      ...
      Ports:
          analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, not available)
          analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, available)
      Active Port: analog-output-headphones
      Formats:
          pcm
  ...
  ```

  To set it:

  ```
  pactl set-sink-port <sink-id/name> <port-name>
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  pactl set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones
  ```

**To change the Master Channel**

Following [this tutorial](http://pablo-blog.blueoakdb.com/2012/07/kmix-automatically-switch-master.html), you can set the master channel using `qdbus` as follows:

1. Find the Master Mixer for each of your devices with the following command. First manually set the Master Channel to the one you want to check, then run the command:

   ```
   qdbus org.kde.kmix /Mixers org.kde.KMix.MixSet.currentMasterControl
   ```
2. Using the result of that command and the audio sink you wish you control, use the following syntax to change your master channel:

   ```
   qdbus org.kde.kmix /Mixers org.kde.KMix.MixSet.setCurrentMaster "[insert Mixer]" "[insert sink]" 2>&1 > /dev/null
   ```
3. In the end, the script to switch all current audio to a new channel, set it as the default, and set it as the master channel looks like the following:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-stereo
   pactl set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-mono
   INPUTS=($(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep index | awk '{print $2}'))
   for i in ${INPUTS[*]}; do pacmd move-sink-input $i alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-stereo &> /dev/null; done
   qdbus org.kde.kmix /Mixers org.kde.KMix.MixSet.setCurrentMaster "PulseAudio::Playback_Devices=:1" "alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-stereo" 2>&1 > /dev/null
   ```

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but I don't think my install is using PulseAudio. I can use the commands, but the current default source and sink are not the same as what's shown in the Phonon menu. And changing them seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Ryan , I just tested it in openSUSE 13.1 KDE , seem to work well. The only thing I noticed: the Phonon panel does not refresh its interface in if settings  changed from PulseAudio. Could you install `pavucontrol` then open the 3 together on screen (terminal w/pactl + pavucontrol panel + phonon panel). Try to change setting from each one and watch. Sometime, you need to close phonon the open it again to see to real setting state.

Comment: I found out you can create a new profile that link both sink together and so they are always visible to `pactl list short sinks`, see my answer below

Comment: hii i wrode dhe answer  dhere  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947878/how-to-disable-next-key-keycode-117-which-is-constantly-being-triggered/1366531#1366531)

Comment: @PamIx ok well received

Comment: @PamIx Could you comment under the question, so it is possible to address you with notification.

Comment: @user.dz I cant my reputation is less than is 1 there also I tried the answer but it didn't  work I think that's some mechanical problem with my device by the way thanks for the concern wish you luck

Comment: Why is the `qdbus` bit for setting the master channel needed? It seems to be working fine without it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderRevo At time of writing this, KDE Kmix wasn't monitoring for PulseAudio. So after updating PA, we had to tell Kmix about same change. It is possible that Kmix already fix this gap.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401492/how-to-output-unique-audio-to-multiple-ports-profiles-of-a-pulseaudio-card) I finally found a solution, see the below instruction

**Show always HDMI output in the mixed**
We will create a new profile that link both profiles "Analog audio" and "HDMI audio".

From my understanding this file 
`/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf` list all mapping profiles between Alsa and Pulseaudio.

**1.**
Find the mapping that are related to your `Analog profile` and `HDMI profile` definition.
(**description:** should match the **Device Profiles** shown in *Audio Volume* Kde setting module )

For me are the following:

```
[Mapping analog-stereo]
device-strings = front:%f
channel-map = left,right
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-lineout analog-output-speaker analog-output-headphones analog-output-headphones-2
paths-input = analog-input-front-mic analog-input-rear-mic analog-input-internal-mic analog-input-dock-mic analog-input analog-input-mic analog-input-linein analog-input-aux analog-input-video analog-input-tvtuner analog-input-fm analog-input-mic-line analog-input-headphone-mic analog-input-headset-mic
priority = 10

[Mapping hdmi-stereo-extra1]
description = Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
device-strings = hdmi:%f,1
paths-output = hdmi-output-1
channel-map = left,right
priority = 2
direction = output
```

**2.**
On the base of the above Mapping definition I have created the following new profile that group both the above ones:

```
[Profile output:analog-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo-extra1]
description = All
output-mappings = analog-stereo hdmi-stereo-extra1
input-mappings = analog-stereo
```

**3.**
Restart pulse audio with this command:

```
pulseaudio --kill; sleep 1; pulseaudio --start
```

**4.**
Go to KDE phonon settings > Audio Hardware setup and select the new profile.
 [image: 2 profiles in the mixer]

Now you should see both profile in the mixed and so you'll be able to switch easy:

[image: HDMI is always shown in the mixer now]
I would suggest to use this plasmoid mixer: https://store.kde.org/p/1100894/

**(extra step) Force both output enabled**

If you don't mind having both computer speaker and TV output audio in the same time ( so basically you don't have to switch the audio output ever ).

You can select the below setting and then you'll have a new entry in the mixer

[image]

Comment: This is just great, works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Building upon previous comments, I wrote the following script and bind it to a hotkey for use in KDE Plasma to toggle between my two audio devices. I like having the control of my audio source as opposed to completely automating this process.

Change your audio devices as appropriate. Use `pactl list short sinks` to determine your devices.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Audio sinks
HEADSET='alsa_output.usb-Corsair_Corsair_VOID_PRO_Wireless_Gaming_Headset-00.analog-stereo'
SPEAKERS='alsa_output.pci-0000_1f_00.3.analog-stereo'

# Get current audio sink
CURRENTDEV=$(pactl list short sinks | grep RUNNING | awk {'print $2'})

# Determine our next audio sink
if [[ "$CURRENTDEV" == "$HEADSET" ]]; then
    NEXTDEV=$SPEAKERS
else
    NEXTDEV=$HEADSET
fi

# Set our default device
pactl set-default-sink $NEXTDEV

# Move current streams (dont check for null, if null you wont see heads up display of audio change)
INPUTS=($(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep index | awk '{print $2}'))
for i in ${INPUTS[*]}; do pacmd move-sink-input $i $NEXTDEV &> /dev/null; done
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation is simple. I have two output some hdmi and some analog, so based on user.dz answer (thanks) I wrote this little script and call it with keyboard shortcuts.

```
#!/bin/bash
# parameter: "hdmi" or "analog"

output=`pactl list short sinks |grep $1 | cut -f1`

pactl set-default-sink $output

for i in `pacmd list-sink-inputs |grep index: | awk '{print $2}'`; do
  pacmd move-sink-input $i $output
done
```

If you have other interfaces you can look for unique pattern in "pactl list short sinks" output and call the script with whatever parameter you want.

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere ... I did not find ... I made a script in python, use it)

```
import os
speakers = []
st = 0
au = os.popen("pacmd list-sinks")
audiotm = au.read()
audio = list(audiotm.split())
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(audio) if x == "name:"]
for num in range(len(indices)):
    speakers.append(audio[indices[num]+1])
for num in range(len(speakers)):
    speakers[num] = speakers[num][1:len(speakers[num])-1]
dir = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dir = dir[:-5]
try: f = open(dir + "lststate.txt","r");st = int(f.read()) ;f.close();
except:f = open(dir + "lststate.txt","w");f.write(str(st)); f.close();
if st == len(speakers): st = 0;
OUT = speakers[st]
st += 1
f = open(dir + "lststate.txt","w");f.write(str(st)); f.close();
z = os.popen("pactl list short sink-inputs")
OUTID = z.read().split()
x = os.popen("pacmd set-default-sink " + OUT)
for num in range(0,len(OUTID),7):
    y = os.popen("pactl move-sink-input " + OUTID[num] + " " + OUT)
exit()
```